# Custom Cloudflare Purge based on new data updated in Frontend

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, cloudflare, cdn, browser-cache

I have a Micro-Services Deployments running on an EKS Cluster and a substantial amount of media stored in Frontend Services.

**I'm looking to implement a custom cache purge mechanism in Cloudflare, specifically for media and certain paths, which is Updated by frontend updates.**

Currently, I've integrated Cloudflare into my CI/CD process using the Cloudflare API to purge all content with domain excemption. Here's the command I'm using:

`curl -X POST "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/tokenhere/purge_cache" -H "X-Auth-Email: secret@gmail.com" -H "X-Auth-Key: TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json"  --data '{"files":[{"url":"www.domain.com/*"}]}'`

I'm in Search on how to achieve this level of cache purging with Cloudflare. Where Cloudflare Only Purges the Files and Paths Updated in the New Deployments.

Any insights or Best Practices instructions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

All purge options are listed here. You can choose based on your requirement.

- [Purge cache · Cloudflare Cache (CDN) docs](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/how-to/purge-cache/)